# Xcode - Custom TableViewCell Shows Wrong Data

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, tableview

I was trying to create a custom TableView Cell in Storyboards. The correct data shows when the ViewController is loaded. However, when I start scrolling back and forth, the data is showing up in random cells, not in the right place. I was also trying to make the text of a Right Detail cell bold programmatically like this:

```
        if dayOfWeek!-1 == indexPath.row {
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: (cell.textLabel?.font.pointSize)!)
        cell.detailTextLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: (cell.detailTextLabel?.font.pointSize)!)
    }
```

However, similar things happened: the bold seems right at first and the text are bolded in random cells. Any idea how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: didn't see where you set your data in textLabel or detailtextlabel? please clarify.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        // your cleanup code
    }
}
```

in cell for indexpath

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: CustomTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
 if dayOfWeek!-1 == indexPath.row {
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: (cell.textLabel?.font.pointSize)!)
        cell.detailTextLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: (cell.detailTextLabel?.font.pointSize)!)
    }
        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to reload the tableview when you have called it.
The random shown data is due to the property undertaken by the various cell  from the each other.

You have faced these type of problem when you are using the multiple tableview on the single view.
Hence the cell having the elements wrongly considered the properties, which can be solved  by refreshing the table view which is "RELOAD".

If the Data coming is from the API , then it would be an advantage, put  the Response data to your main array and Reload the table view .